# Namespace of class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, methods, namespaces

I'm unclear on the namespace of the class name inside the class.

Here is an example:

```
class SomeClass():
    some_class_attribute = SomeClass.create_attribute()
    @classmethod 
    def create_attribute(cls, int): 
        return str(int)
```

Is there any problem with the line `some_class_attribute = SomeClass.create_attribute()`?

When I'm writing a class in Spyder IDE, the class works, but Spyder displays a warning "Undefined name SomeClass".

Comment: Have a look at [How can I access a classmethod from inside a class in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900515/how-can-i-access-a-classmethod-from-inside-a-class-in-python)

Comment: The *class doesn't exist until after the class body is finished executing*. Therefore, you cannot use the class inside the class body (unless in a method).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga What you said is what I was thinking.  However, if I can't use the class inside the class body, why does it work?

Comment: @user3731622 this *does not work*, it raises a `NameError`, just as the IDE warns you it will. I suspect you have left-over variables in your interactive interpreter session (e.g., previous runs).

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was just checking that.  What happened was, in Spyder I ran the script containing the class def without the attribute.  Then I added the class atrribute which used the class name and ran the script again.  Now I could access `SomeClass.some_class_attribute`.  Seems like the interpreter got a little fooled and used the previously defined `SomeClass` name when it encountered the line `some_class_attribute = SomeClass.create_attribute()`.