# How to access built-in class attributes in class body at class definition time?

Tags: python

Once a class is constructed (i.e. defined, not instantiated), I can access its dunder attributes.

```
>>> class Foo:
...    'This is a class.'
>>> Foo.__doc__
'This is a class.'
```

Is there any way I can access `__doc__` *while* the class is being defined?

```
class Foo:
    'This is a class.'
    a = Foo.__doc__  # does not work because Foo is not defined yet
```

Or can this not be done because `__doc__` is only assigned by the meta class *after* the class body has been executed? Is there an alias for it then? How about other dunder attributes/methods?

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035423/python-how-to-refer-to-the-class-from-within-it-like-the-recursive-function, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13900515/how-can-i-access-a-classmethod-from-inside-a-class-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the docstring as an attribute of the class (because the class object doesn't exist yet), but you *can* grab it directly, like a local variable:

```
class Foo:
    'This is a class.'
    a = __doc__
```

This sets the value of `a` as one would expect:

```
>>> Foo.a
'This is a class.'
```

***However***, I haven't been able to find any information about this behavior in the official documentation. It's unclear if being able to access `__doc__` like this is an official feature or a mere implementation detail. If you want to make absolutely sure that your code doesn't rely on what's possibly an implementation detail, you can manually assign to `__doc__` like so:

```
class Foo:
    a = __doc__ = 'This is a class.'
```

It's a little ugly, but it's guaranteed to work.

Comment: Duh, I was sure your first option was the first thing I tried. Well, I must have done something wrong... Anyway, I am really glad to know that you can *assign* to `__doc__` too.

Comment: Also, for any future reader that might come across this: I ended up solving my specific problem by using a decorator. Turned out to be much more elegant.